# find month days

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I need to find how many days have in this month which we can find with today's date

```
select to_number(to_date('01.02.2011')-to_date('01.01.2011')) from dual;
```

not this query 
Have  any other queries?

Comment: You should accept one of the answers if it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select extract(day from last_day(sysdate)) from dual
```

?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a `trunc(<date>, 'mm')` (which returns the first day of the month) and an `add_months(<date>,1)` which add one month to a particular day. So, in order to find out how many days the month has in which we currently are (i.e. `sysdate`), you could go with something like:

```
select  
  add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'),1) - trunc(sysdate, 'mm') 
from 
  dual;
```

Comment: check as well LAST_DAY which gives you the last day of the month

Answer (score 1):

```
select DateDiff(Day,GETDATE(),DateAdd(month,1,GETDATE()))
```