# Check in SQL how many times each day comes in a each month

Tags: mysql, sql

I want a sql query that gives me a count of how many times monday, tuesday...etc come in a particular month. Can anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: Do you already have something in mind that you want to share with us?

Comment: Please tell what specific DBMS you intend to use (e.g. Oracle, MySQL, etc). There might be some solution through vendor-specific features that is not available through standard SQL.

Comment: Do not use a database to do this. A database should be uses to store/search data, not do calculations that have nothing to do with your data

Answer (score 1):

**(edited)**

Given the [MySQL date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) , and some simpler problems ([how many days in month](http://forums.databasejournal.com/showthread.php?45380-sql-query-for-number-days-in-a-month-amp-number-of-sundays-in-a-month...) or [find month days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712863/find-month-days)) I have made out this expression:

```
ceil((day(last_day($dateInMonth)) - (7 + dayofweek(last_day($dateInMonth)) - $weekday) % 7) / 7)
```

where $dateInMonth is a date in the requested month (e.g. `'2012-09-05'` for today), and $weekday is the weekday number in SQL (1 for sunday, 7 for saturday).

For example: This month (Sept 2012) has 4 fridays, but 5 saturdays:

```
select ceil((day(last_day('2012-09-05')) - (7 + dayofweek(last_day('2012-09-05')) - 6) % 7) / 7);
select ceil((day(last_day('2012-09-05')) - (7 + dayofweek(last_day('2012-09-05')) - 7) % 7) / 7);
```

**Other possibilities:**

- Invoke some external code (e.g. Java, if DBMS allows)
- Create a table (e.g. DAYSPERMONTH) with that precalculated data (if months might be within a reasonable range)

Answer (score 0):

check [sql method](http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/Using-SQL-to-find-the-number-of-Sundays-in-a-month). to find a specific days count in month.

Answer (score 0):

This function can be used forever and has multiple uses.

All you have to do is create the function and run the proper `select` statement.  I have provided a sample at the end of the function (Which has been taken from [this site](http://sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519)).

Just replace the word `*database*` at the top and bottom with your database name:

```
use *database*    
      SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
        GO

        SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
        GO


        create function [dbo].[F_TABLE_DATE]
        (
            @FIRST_DATE     datetime,
            @LAST_DATE      datetime
        )
        /*
        Function: dbo.F_TABLE_DATE

        This function returns a date table containing all dates
        from @FIRST_DATE through @LAST_DATE inclusive.
        @FIRST_DATE must be less than or equal to @LAST_DATE.
        The valid date range is 1754-01-01 through 9997-12-31.
        If any input parameters are invalid, the function will produce
        an error.

        The table returned by F_TABLE_DATE contains a date and
        columns with many calculated attributes of that date.
        It is designed to make it convenient to get various commonly
        needed date attributes without having to program and test
        the same logic in many applications.

        F_TABLE_DATE is primarily intended to load a permanant
        date table, but it can be used directly by an application
        when the date range needed falls outside the range loaded
        in a permanant table.

        If F_TABLE_DATE is used to load a permanant table, the create
        table code can be copied from this function.  For a permanent
        date table, most columns should be indexed to produce the
        best application performance.


        Column Descriptions
        ------------------------------------------------------------------


        DATE_ID               
            Unique ID = Days since 1753-01-01

        DATE                            
            Date at Midnight(00:00:00.000)

        NEXT_DAY_DATE                   
            Next day after DATE at Midnight(00:00:00.000)
            Intended to be used in queries against columns
            containing datetime values (1998-12-13 14:35:16)
            that need to join to a DATE.
            Example:

            from
                MyTable a
                join
                DATE b
                on  a.DateTimeCol >= b. DATE    and
                    a.DateTimeCol < b.NEXT_DAY_DATE

        YEAR                            
            Year number in format YYYY, Example = 2005

        YEAR_QUARTER                    
            Year and Quarter number in format YYYYQ, Example = 20052

        YEAR_MONTH                      
            Year and Month number in format YYYYMM, Example = 200511

        YEAR_DAY_OF_YEAR                
            Year and Day of Year number in format YYYYDDD, Example = 2005364

        QUARTER                         
            Quarter number in format Q, Example = 4

        MONTH                           
            Month number in format MM, Example = 11

        DAY_OF_YEAR                     
            Day of Year number in format DDD, Example = 362

        DAY_OF_MONTH                    
            Day of Month number in format DD, Example = 31

        DAY_OF_WEEK                     
            Day of week number, Sun=1, Mon=2, Tue=3, Wed=4, Thu=5, Fri=6, Sat=7

        YEAR_NAME                       
            Year name text in format YYYY, Example = 2005

        YEAR_QUARTER_NAME               
            Year Quarter name text in format YYYY QQ, Example = 2005 Q3

        YEAR_MONTH_NAME                 
            Year Month name text in format YYYY MMM, Example = 2005 Mar

        YEAR_MONTH_NAME_LONG            
            Year Month long name text in format YYYY MMMMMMMMM,
            Example = 2005 September

        QUARTER_NAME                    
            Quarter name text in format QQ, Example = Q1

        MONTH_NAME                      
            Month name text in format MMM, Example = Mar

        MONTH_NAME_LONG                 
            Month long name text in format MMMMMMMMM, Example = September

        WEEKDAY_NAME                    
            Weekday name text in format DDD, Example = Tue

        WEEKDAY_NAME_LONG               
            Weekday long name text in format DDDDDDDDD, Example = Wednesday

        START_OF_YEAR_DATE              
            First Day of Year that DATE is in

        END_OF_YEAR_DATE                
            Last Day of Year that DATE is in

        START_OF_QUARTER_DATE           
            First Day of Quarter that DATE is in

        END_OF_QUARTER_DATE             
            Last Day of Quarter that DATE is in

        START_OF_MONTH_DATE             
            First Day of Month that DATE is in

        END_OF_MONTH_DATE               
            Last Day of Month that DATE is in

        *** Start and End of week columns allow selections by week
        *** for any week start date needed.

        START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SUN_DATE 
            First Day of Week starting Sunday that DATE is in

        END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SUN_DATE   
            Last Day of Week starting Sunday that DATE is in

        START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_MON_DATE 
            First Day of Week starting Monday that DATE is in

        END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_MON_DATE   
            Last Day of Week starting Monday that DATE is in

        START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_TUE_DATE 
            First Day of Week starting Tuesday that DATE is in

        END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_TUE_DATE   
            Last Day of Week starting Tuesday that DATE is in

        START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_WED_DATE 
            First Day of Week starting Wednesday that DATE is in

        END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_WED_DATE   
            Last Day of Week starting Wednesday that DATE is in

        START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_THU_DATE 
            First Day of Week starting Thursday that DATE is in

        END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_THU_DATE   
            Last Day of Week starting Thursday that DATE is in

        START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_FRI_DATE 
            First Day of Week starting Friday that DATE is in

        END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_FRI_DATE   
            Last Day of Week starting Friday that DATE is in

        START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SAT_DATE 
            First Day of Week starting Saturday that DATE is in

        END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SAT_DATE   
            Last Day of Week starting Saturday that DATE is in

        *** Sequence No columns are intended to allow easy offsets by
        *** Quarter, Month, or Week for applications that need to look at
        *** Last or Next Quarter, Month, or Week.  Thay can also be used to
        *** generate dynamic cross tab results by Quarter, Month, or Week.

        QUARTER_SEQ_NO                  
            Sequential Quarter number as offset from Quarter starting 1753/01/01

        MONTH_SEQ_NO                    
            Sequential Month number as offset from Month starting 1753/01/01

        WEEK_STARTING_SUN_SEQ_NO        
            Sequential Week number as offset from Week starting Sunday, 1753/01/07

        WEEK_STARTING_MON_SEQ_NO        
            Sequential Week number as offset from Week starting Monday, 1753/01/01

        WEEK_STARTING_TUE_SEQ_NO        
            Sequential Week number as offset from Week starting Tuesday, 1753/01/02

        WEEK_STARTING_WED_SEQ_NO        
            Sequential Week number as offset from Week starting Wednesday, 1753/01/03

        WEEK_STARTING_THU_SEQ_NO        
            Sequential Week number as offset from Week starting Thursday, 1753/01/04

        WEEK_STARTING_FRI_SEQ_NO        
            Sequential Week number as offset from Week starting Friday, 1753/01/05

        WEEK_STARTING_SAT_SEQ_NO        
            Sequential Week number as offset from Week starting Saturday, 1753/01/06

        JULIAN_DATE                     
            Julian Date number as offset from noon on January 1, 4713 BCE
            to noon on day of DATE in system of Joseph Scaliger

        MODIFIED_JULIAN_DATE            
            Modified Julian Date number as offset from midnight(00:00:00.000) on
            1858/11/17 to midnight(00:00:00.000) on day of DATE

        ISO_DATE                        
            ISO 8601 Date in format YYYY-MM-DD, Example = 2004-02-29

        ISO_YEAR_WEEK_NO                
            ISO 8601 year and week in format YYYYWW, Example = 200403

        ISO_WEEK_NO                     
            ISO 8601 week of year in format WW, Example = 52

        ISO_DAY_OF_WEEK                 
            ISO 8601 Day of week number, 
            Mon=1, Tue=2, Wed=3, Thu=4, Fri=5, Sat=6, Sun=7

        ISO_YEAR_WEEK_NAME              
            ISO 8601 year and week in format YYYY-WNN, Example = 2004-W52

        ISO_YEAR_WEEK_DAY_OF_WEEK_NAME  
            ISO 8601 year, week, and day of week in format YYYY-WNN-D,
            Example = 2004-W52-2

        DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD          
            Text date in format YYYY/MM/DD, Example = 2004/02/29

        DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_M_D            
            Text date in format YYYY/M/D, Example = 2004/2/9

        DATE_FORMAT_MM_DD_YYYY          
            Text date in format MM/DD/YYYY, Example = 06/05/2004

        DATE_FORMAT_M_D_YYYY            
            Text date in format M/D/YYYY, Example = 6/5/2004

        DATE_FORMAT_MMM_D_YYYY          
            Text date in format MMM D, YYYY, Example = Jan 4, 2006

        DATE_FORMAT_MMMMMMMMM_D_YYYY    
            Text date in format MMMMMMMMM D, YYYY, Example = September 3, 2004

        DATE_FORMAT_MM_DD_YY            
            Text date in format MM/DD/YY, Example = 06/05/97

        DATE_FORMAT_M_D_YY              
            Text date in format M/D/YY, Example = 6/5/97

        */

        returns  @DATE table 
        (
        [DATE_ID]               [int]       not null 
            primary key clustered,
        [DATE]                  [datetime]  not null ,
        [NEXT_DAY_DATE]             [datetime]  not null ,
        [YEAR]                  [smallint]  not null ,
        [YEAR_QUARTER]              [int]   not null ,
        [YEAR_MONTH]                [int]       not null ,
        [YEAR_DAY_OF_YEAR]          [int]       not null ,
        [QUARTER]               [tinyint]   not null ,
        [MONTH]                 [tinyint]   not null ,
        [DAY_OF_YEAR]               [smallint]  not null ,
        [DAY_OF_MONTH]              [smallint]  not null ,
        [DAY_OF_WEEK]               [tinyint]   not null ,

        [YEAR_NAME]             [varchar] (4)   not null ,
        [YEAR_QUARTER_NAME]         [varchar] (7)   not null ,
        [YEAR_MONTH_NAME]           [varchar] (8)   not null ,
        [YEAR_MONTH_NAME_LONG]          [varchar] (14)  not null ,
        [QUARTER_NAME]              [varchar] (2)   not null ,
        [MONTH_NAME]                [varchar] (3)   not null ,
        [MONTH_NAME_LONG]           [varchar] (9)   not null ,
        [WEEKDAY_NAME]              [varchar] (3)   not null ,
        [WEEKDAY_NAME_LONG]         [varchar] (9)   not null ,

        [START_OF_YEAR_DATE]            [datetime]  not null ,
        [END_OF_YEAR_DATE]          [datetime]  not null ,
        [START_OF_QUARTER_DATE]         [datetime]  not null ,
        [END_OF_QUARTER_DATE]           [datetime]  not null ,
        [START_OF_MONTH_DATE]           [datetime]  not null ,
        [END_OF_MONTH_DATE]         [datetime]  not null ,

        [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SUN_DATE]   [datetime]  not null ,
        [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SUN_DATE]     [datetime]  not null ,
        [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_MON_DATE]   [datetime]  not null ,
        [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_MON_DATE]     [datetime]  not null ,
        [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_TUE_DATE]   [datetime]  not null ,
        [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_TUE_DATE]     [datetime]  not null ,
        [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_WED_DATE]   [datetime]  not null ,
        [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_WED_DATE]     [datetime]  not null ,
        [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_THU_DATE]   [datetime]  not null ,
        [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_THU_DATE]     [datetime]  not null ,
        [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_FRI_DATE]   [datetime]  not null ,
        [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_FRI_DATE]     [datetime]  not null ,
        [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SAT_DATE]   [datetime]  not null ,
        [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SAT_DATE]     [datetime]  not null ,

        [QUARTER_SEQ_NO]            [int]       not null ,
        [MONTH_SEQ_NO]              [int]       not null ,

        [WEEK_STARTING_SUN_SEQ_NO]      [int]       not null ,
        [WEEK_STARTING_MON_SEQ_NO]      [int]       not null ,
        [WEEK_STARTING_TUE_SEQ_NO]      [int]       not null ,
        [WEEK_STARTING_WED_SEQ_NO]      [int]       not null ,
        [WEEK_STARTING_THU_SEQ_NO]      [int]       not null ,
        [WEEK_STARTING_FRI_SEQ_NO]      [int]       not null ,
        [WEEK_STARTING_SAT_SEQ_NO]      [int]       not null ,

        [JULIAN_DATE]               [int]       not null ,
        [MODIFIED_JULIAN_DATE]          [int]       not null ,

        [ISO_DATE]              [varchar](10)   not null ,
        [ISO_YEAR_WEEK_NO]          [int]       not null ,
        [ISO_WEEK_NO]               [smallint]  not null ,
        [ISO_DAY_OF_WEEK]           [tinyint]   not null ,
        [ISO_YEAR_WEEK_NAME]            [varchar](8)    not null ,
        [ISO_YEAR_WEEK_DAY_OF_WEEK_NAME]    [varchar](10)   not null ,

        [DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD]        [varchar](10)   not null ,
        [DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_M_D]          [varchar](10)   not null ,
        [DATE_FORMAT_MM_DD_YYYY]        [varchar](10)   not null ,
        [DATE_FORMAT_M_D_YYYY]          [varchar](10)   not null ,
        [DATE_FORMAT_MMM_D_YYYY]        [varchar](12)   not null ,
        [DATE_FORMAT_MMMMMMMMM_D_YYYY]      [varchar](18)   not null ,
        [DATE_FORMAT_MM_DD_YY]          [varchar](8)    not null ,
        [DATE_FORMAT_M_D_YY]            [varchar](8)    not null 
        ) 
        as
        begin
        declare @cr         varchar(2)
        select @cr          = char(13)+Char(10)
        declare @ErrorMessage       varchar(400)
        declare @START_DATE     datetime
        declare @END_DATE       datetime
        declare @LOW_DATE   datetime

        declare @start_no   int
        declare @end_no int

        -- Verify @FIRST_DATE is not null 
        if @FIRST_DATE is null
            begin
            select @ErrorMessage =
                '@FIRST_DATE cannot be null'
            goto Error_Exit
            end

        -- Verify @LAST_DATE is not null 
        if @LAST_DATE is null
            begin
            select @ErrorMessage =
                '@LAST_DATE cannot be null'
            goto Error_Exit
            end

        -- Verify @FIRST_DATE is not before 1754-01-01
        IF  @FIRST_DATE < '17540101'    begin
            select @ErrorMessage =
                '@FIRST_DATE cannot before 1754-01-01'+
                ', @FIRST_DATE = '+
                isnull(convert(varchar(40),@FIRST_DATE,121),'NULL')
            goto Error_Exit
            end

        -- Verify @LAST_DATE is not after 9997-12-31
        IF  @LAST_DATE > '99971231' begin
            select @ErrorMessage =
                '@LAST_DATE cannot be after 9997-12-31'+
                ', @LAST_DATE = '+
                isnull(convert(varchar(40),@LAST_DATE,121),'NULL')
            goto Error_Exit
            end

        -- Verify @FIRST_DATE is not after @LAST_DATE
        if @FIRST_DATE > @LAST_DATE
            begin
            select @ErrorMessage =
                '@FIRST_DATE cannot be after @LAST_DATE'+
                ', @FIRST_DATE = '+
                isnull(convert(varchar(40),@FIRST_DATE,121),'NULL')+
                ', @LAST_DATE = '+
                isnull(convert(varchar(40),@LAST_DATE,121),'NULL')
            goto Error_Exit
            end

        -- Set @START_DATE = @FIRST_DATE at midnight
        select @START_DATE  = dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,@FIRST_DATE),0)
        -- Set @END_DATE = @LAST_DATE at midnight
        select @END_DATE    = dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,@LAST_DATE),0)
        -- Set @LOW_DATE = earliest possible SQL Server datetime
        select @LOW_DATE    = convert(datetime,'17530101')

        -- Find the number of day from 1753-01-01 to @START_DATE and @END_DATE
        select  @start_no   = datediff(dd,@LOW_DATE,@START_DATE) ,
            @end_no = datediff(dd,@LOW_DATE,@END_DATE)

        -- Declare number tables
        declare @num1 table (NUMBER int not null primary key clustered)
        declare @num2 table (NUMBER int not null primary key clustered)
        declare @num3 table (NUMBER int not null primary key clustered)

        -- Declare table of ISO Week ranges
        declare @ISO_WEEK table
        (
        [ISO_WEEK_YEAR]         int     not null
            primary key clustered,
        [ISO_WEEK_YEAR_START_DATE]  datetime    not null,
        [ISO_WEEK_YEAR_END_DATE]    Datetime    not null
        )

        -- Find rows needed in number tables
        declare @rows_needed        int
        declare @rows_needed_root   int
        select  @rows_needed        = @end_no - @start_no + 1
        select  @rows_needed        =
                case
                when @rows_needed < 10
                then 10
                else @rows_needed
                end
        select  @rows_needed_root   = convert(int,ceiling(sqrt(@rows_needed)))

        -- Load number 0 to 16
        insert into @num1 (NUMBER)
        select NUMBER = 0 union all select  1 union all select  2 union all
        select          3 union all select  4 union all select  5 union all
        select          6 union all select  7 union all select  8 union all
        select          9 union all select 10 union all select 11 union all
        select         12 union all select 13 union all select 14 union all
        select         15
        order by
            1
        -- Load table with numbers zero thru square root of the number of rows needed +1
        insert into @num2 (NUMBER)
        select
            NUMBER = a.NUMBER+(16*b.NUMBER)+(256*c.NUMBER)
        from
            @num1 a cross join @num1 b cross join @num1 c
        where
            a.NUMBER+(16*b.NUMBER)+(256*c.NUMBER) <
            @rows_needed_root
        order by
            1

        -- Load table with the number of rows needed for the date range
        insert into @num3 (NUMBER)
        select
            NUMBER = a.NUMBER+(@rows_needed_root*b.NUMBER)
        from
            @num2 a
            cross join
            @num2 b
        where
            a.NUMBER+(@rows_needed_root*b.NUMBER) < @rows_needed
        order by
            1

        declare @iso_start_year int
        declare @iso_end_year   int

        select  @iso_start_year = datepart(year,dateadd(year,-1,@start_date))
        select  @iso_end_year   = datepart(year,dateadd(year,1,@end_date))

        -- Load table with start and end dates for ISO week years
        insert into @ISO_WEEK
            (
            [ISO_WEEK_YEAR],
            [ISO_WEEK_YEAR_START_DATE],
            [ISO_WEEK_YEAR_END_DATE]
            )
        select
            [ISO_WEEK_YEAR] = a.NUMBER,
            [0ISO_WEEK_YEAR_START_DATE] =
                dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,@LOW_DATE,
                dateadd(day,3,dateadd(year,a.[NUMBER]-1900,0))
                )/7)*7,@LOW_DATE),
            [ISO_WEEK_YEAR_END_DATE]    =
                dateadd(dd,-1,dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,@LOW_DATE,
                dateadd(day,3,dateadd(year,a.[NUMBER]+1-1900,0))
                )/7)*7,@LOW_DATE))
        from
            (
            select
                NUMBER = NUMBER+@iso_start_year
            from
                @num3
            where
                NUMBER+@iso_start_year <= @iso_end_year
            ) a
        order by
            a.NUMBER

        -- Load Date table
        insert into @DATE
        select
            [DATE_ID]           = a.[DATE_ID] ,
            [DATE]              = a.[DATE] ,

            [NEXT_DAY_DATE]         =
                dateadd(day,1,a.[DATE]) ,

            [YEAR]          =
                datepart(year,a.[DATE]) ,
            [YEAR_QUARTER]      =
                (10*datepart(year,a.[DATE]))+datepart(quarter,a.[DATE]) ,

            [YEAR_MONTH]        =
                (100*datepart(year,a.[DATE]))+datepart(month,a.[DATE]) ,
            [YEAR_DAY_OF_YEAR]      =
                (1000*datepart(year,a.[DATE]))+
                datediff(dd,dateadd(yy,datediff(yy,0,a.[DATE]),0),a.[DATE])+1 ,
            [QUARTER]       =
                datepart(quarter,a.[DATE]) ,
            [MONTH]     =
                datepart(month,a.[DATE]) ,
            [DAY_OF_YEAR]           =
                datediff(dd,dateadd(yy,datediff(yy,0,a.[DATE]),0),a.[DATE])+1 ,
            [DAY_OF_MONTH]          =
                datepart(day,a.[DATE]) ,
            [DAY_OF_WEEK]       =
                -- Sunday = 1, Monday = 2, ,,,Saturday = 7
                (datediff(dd,'17530107',a.[DATE])%7)+1  ,
            [YEAR_NAME]     =
                datename(year,a.[DATE]) ,
            [YEAR_QUARTER_NAME] =
                datename(year,a.[DATE])+' Q'+datename(quarter,a.[DATE]) ,
            [YEAR_MONTH_NAME]   =
                datename(year,a.[DATE])+' '+left(datename(month,a.[DATE]),3) ,
            [YEAR_MONTH_NAME_LONG]  =
                datename(year,a.[DATE])+' '+datename(month,a.[DATE]) ,
            [QUARTER_NAME]      =
                'Q'+datename(quarter,a.[DATE]) ,
            [MONTH_NAME]        =
                left(datename(month,a.[DATE]),3) ,
            [MONTH_NAME_LONG]   =
                datename(month,a.[DATE]) ,
            [WEEKDAY_NAME]      =
                left(datename(weekday,a.[DATE]),3) ,
            [WEEKDAY_NAME_LONG] =
                datename(weekday,a.[DATE]),

            [START_OF_YEAR_DATE]    =
                dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,a.[DATE]),0) ,
            [END_OF_YEAR_DATE]  =
                dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,a.[DATE])+1,0)) ,

            [START_OF_QUARTER_DATE] =
                dateadd(quarter,datediff(quarter,0,a.[DATE]),0) ,
            [END_OF_QUARTER_DATE]   =
                dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(quarter,datediff(quarter,0,a.[DATE])+1,0)) ,

            [START_OF_MONTH_DATE]   =
                dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,a.[DATE]),0) ,
            [END_OF_MONTH_DATE] =
                dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,a.[DATE])+1,0)),

            [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SUN_DATE]   =
                dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,'17530107',a.[DATE])/7)*7,'17530107'),
            [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SUN_DATE]     =
                dateadd(dd,((datediff(dd,'17530107',a.[DATE])/7)*7)+6,'17530107'),

            [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_MON_DATE]   =
                dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,'17530101',a.[DATE])/7)*7,'17530101'),
            [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_MON_DATE]     =
                dateadd(dd,((datediff(dd,'17530101',a.[DATE])/7)*7)+6,'17530101'),

            [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_TUE_DATE]   =
                dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,'17530102',a.[DATE])/7)*7,'17530102'),
            [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_TUE_DATE]     =
                dateadd(dd,((datediff(dd,'17530102',a.[DATE])/7)*7)+6,'17530102'),

            [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_WED_DATE]   =
                dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,'17530103',a.[DATE])/7)*7,'17530103'),
            [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_WED_DATE]     =
                dateadd(dd,((datediff(dd,'17530103',a.[DATE])/7)*7)+6,'17530103'),

            [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_THU_DATE]   =
                dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,'17530104',a.[DATE])/7)*7,'17530104'),
            [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_THU_DATE]     =
                dateadd(dd,((datediff(dd,'17530104',a.[DATE])/7)*7)+6,'17530104'),

            [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_FRI_DATE]   =
                dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,'17530105',a.[DATE])/7)*7,'17530105'),
            [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_FRI_DATE]     =
                dateadd(dd,((datediff(dd,'17530105',a.[DATE])/7)*7)+6,'17530105'),

            [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SAT_DATE]   =
                dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,'17530106',a.[DATE])/7)*7,'17530106'),
            [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SAT_DATE]     =
                dateadd(dd,((datediff(dd,'17530106',a.[DATE])/7)*7)+6,'17530106'),

            [QUARTER_SEQ_NO]            = 
                datediff(quarter,@LOW_DATE,a.[DATE]),
            [MONTH_SEQ_NO]              =
                datediff(month,@LOW_DATE,a.[DATE]),

            [WEEK_STARTING_SUN_SEQ_NO]      =
                datediff(day,'17530107',a.[DATE])/7,
            [WEEK_STARTING_MON_SEQ_NO]      =
                datediff(day,'17530101',a.[DATE])/7,
            [WEEK_STARTING_TUE_SEQ_NO]      =
                datediff(day,'17530102',a.[DATE])/7,
            [WEEK_STARTING_WED_SEQ_NO]      =
                datediff(day,'17530103',a.[DATE])/7,
            [WEEK_STARTING_THU_SEQ_NO]      =
                datediff(day,'17530104',a.[DATE])/7,
            [WEEK_STARTING_FRI_SEQ_NO]      =
                datediff(day,'17530105',a.[DATE])/7,
            [WEEK_STARTING_SAT_SEQ_NO]      =
                datediff(day,'17530106',a.[DATE])/7,

            [JULIAN_DATE]           =
                datediff(day,@LOW_DATE,a.[DATE])+2361331,
            [MODIFIED_JULIAN_DATE]      =
                datediff(day,'18581117',a.[DATE]),
        --/*

            [ISO_DATE]      =
                replace(convert(char(10),a.[DATE],111),'/','-') ,

            [ISO_YEAR_WEEK_NO]      =
                (100*b.[ISO_WEEK_YEAR])+
                (datediff(dd,b.[ISO_WEEK_YEAR_START_DATE],a.[DATE])/7)+1 ,

            [ISO_WEEK_NO]       =
                (datediff(dd,b.[ISO_WEEK_YEAR_START_DATE],a.[DATE])/7)+1 ,

            [ISO_DAY_OF_WEEK]       =
                -- Sunday = 1, Monday = 2, ,,,Saturday = 7
                (datediff(dd,@LOW_DATE,a.[DATE])%7)+1  ,

            [ISO_YEAR_WEEK_NAME]        =
                convert(varchar(4),b.[ISO_WEEK_YEAR])+'-W'+
                right('00'+convert(varchar(2),(datediff(dd,b.[ISO_WEEK_YEAR_START_DATE],a.[DATE])/7)+1),2) ,

            [ISO_YEAR_WEEK_DAY_OF_WEEK_NAME]        =
                convert(varchar(4),b.[ISO_WEEK_YEAR])+'-W'+
                right('00'+convert(varchar(2),(datediff(dd,b.[ISO_WEEK_YEAR_START_DATE],a.[DATE])/7)+1),2) +
                '-'+convert(varchar(1),(datediff(dd,@LOW_DATE,a.[DATE])%7)+1) ,
        --*/
            [DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD]        =
                convert(char(10),a.[DATE],111) ,
            [DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_M_D]      = 
                convert(varchar(10),
                convert(varchar(4),year(a.[DATE]))+'/'+
                convert(varchar(2),day(a.[DATE]))+'/'+
                convert(varchar(2),month(a.[DATE]))),
            [DATE_FORMAT_MM_DD_YYYY]        = 
                convert(char(10),a.[DATE],101) ,
            [DATE_FORMAT_M_D_YYYY]      = 
                convert(varchar(10),
                convert(varchar(2),month(a.[DATE]))+'/'+
                convert(varchar(2),day(a.[DATE]))+'/'+
                convert(varchar(4),year(a.[DATE]))),
            [DATE_FORMAT_MMM_D_YYYY]        = 
                convert(varchar(12),
                left(datename(month,a.[DATE]),3)+' '+
                convert(varchar(2),day(a.[DATE]))+', '+
                convert(varchar(4),year(a.[DATE]))),
            [DATE_FORMAT_MMMMMMMMM_D_YYYY]  = 
                convert(varchar(18),
                datename(month,a.[DATE])+' '+
                convert(varchar(2),day(a.[DATE]))+', '+
                convert(varchar(4),year(a.[DATE]))),
            [DATE_FORMAT_MM_DD_YY]      =
                convert(char(8),a.[DATE],1) ,
            [DATE_FORMAT_M_D_YY]        = 
                convert(varchar(8),
                convert(varchar(2),month(a.[DATE]))+'/'+
                convert(varchar(2),day(a.[DATE]))+'/'+
                right(convert(varchar(4),year(a.[DATE])),2))
        from
            (
            -- Derived table is all dates needed for date range
            select  top 100 percent
                [DATE_ID]   = aa.[NUMBER],
                [DATE]      =
                    dateadd(dd,aa.[NUMBER],@LOW_DATE)
            from
                (
                select
                    NUMBER = NUMBER+@start_no 
                from
                    @num3
                where
                    NUMBER+@start_no <= @end_no
                ) aa
            order by
                aa.[NUMBER]
            ) a
            join
            -- Match each date to the proper ISO week year
            @ISO_WEEK b
            on a.[DATE] between 
                b.[ISO_WEEK_YEAR_START_DATE] and 
                b.[ISO_WEEK_YEAR_END_DATE]
        order by
            a.[DATE_ID]

        return

        Error_Exit:

        -- Return a pesudo error message by trying to
        -- convert an error message string to an int.
        -- This method is used because the error displays
        -- the string it was trying to convert, and so the
        -- calling application sees a formatted error message.

        declare @error int

        set @error = convert(int,@cr+@cr+
        '*******************************************************************'+@cr+
        '* Error in function F_TABLE_DATE:'+@cr+'* '+
        isnull(@ErrorMessage,'Unknown Error')+@cr+
        '*******************************************************************'+@cr+@cr)

        return

        end




        GO




select YEAR_MONTH_NAME_LONG, WEEKDAY_NAME,COUNT(WEEKDAY_NAME)cnt
from database.dbo.F_TABLE_DATE('2012-01-01',GETDATE())
group by YEAR_MONTH_NAME_LONG, WEEKDAY_NAME
order by YEAR_MONTH_NAME_LONG
```

Comment: That code seems to come from http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519 . No license is specified, it would be nice to give attribution, though.